# How does Miyamoto Usagi tie his ears up?

Tags: miyamoto-usagi

The chatacter [Miyamoto Usagi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miyamoto_Usagi) is often depicted with his ears tied up.

How is that possible for him, given how other similar rabbits ears are so far apart?

[image: Miyamoto Usagi and another rabbit with their ears not tied up]

Comment: Possibly a fool's errand, but [I sent Stan Sakai a tweet](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1546971980095700994).

Comment: My theory (outside of "that's just artistic interpretation") is that his ears are partly pulled across his head with the fur and skin bunching to bridge the gap.

Comment: I'm sure there exist panels of him with ears untied, or showing him tying them up, but I don't have books on hand.

Comment: One of Usagi's close friends is a panda bear.  Joking apart, other rabbits tie their ears similar to Usagi.  https://www.previewsworld.com/SiteImage/MainImage/STL201184.jpg   https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51MVrMY-d4L.jpg